# Linked List Insert

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I want to try  insertion function for linked list. Function holds the record array and link array.for example;

```
head=0

string[0]="Angel"   linked[0]=1 
string[1]="Cesar"   linked[1]=2
string[2]="Eduardo" linked[2]=3 
string[3]="Pamela"  linked[3]=-1/*-1 element does not show*/
```

head is Angel and Angel shows Eduardo.e.g. If you add element Denial,string[4]=Denial linked[4]=2 Denial shows  Eduardo.Attention :---->>string[1]="Cesar"   linked[1]=4 link array is updated.

I am getting some errors in this function.(element can not be added.) a little help

```
   #define SIZE 10


   int main()
   {
   int linked[SIZE]={3,0,4,-1,1};
   char *str[]={"Ellian","Calanthe","Adela","Gardenia","Barbara",NULL};

   return 0;
   }

   void list(int arr[],int head,int linky[]){
   int adr=head;

   while(adr!=-1){

   puts(arr[adr]);
   adr=linky[adr];

   }

   }

   void insert(int arrr[],int head,int linky[],char element){

   int k,N=0,prev,next;
   for(k=0;arrr[k]<NULL;k++)
   N++;

   arrr[N]=element;

   if(element>arrr[head])
   {
  prev=head;
  next=linky[head];

 while((next!=-1) && (arrr[next]<element)){
 prev=next;
 next=linky[next];
 }

 linky[prev]=N;
 linky[N]=next;

  }
 else{

linky=head;
head=N;

 }
 N++;
 listele(arr,N,linky);

 }
```

Comment: Details of your errors and better formatted code would be nice.

Comment: your size++ at the end of insert does nothing. size is a local variable and when the function return nothing outside of it's scope will have been changed if you're doing things this way. it's also impossible to change the value of the size outsize of the functions scope because it's not a variable in the program, it's just a constant in the function call.

Comment: Your code is just wrong, almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

You are using your `string`array contents before initializing them, to avoid undefined behaviour change this:

```
char string[SIZE];
```

to this:

```
char string[SIZE] = {0};
```

If you want your `string` array to start with zeroes inside.

Also notice you are running past the last element of your arrays when you do:

```
link[size] = ...
```

as you array is of exactly `size` elements then the max index you can use is `size - 1`.

Comment: Please update your post with the changes. Also, I updated my answer with other thing I realized.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
#define SIZE 10
```

by

```
int size = 10;
```

and replace

```
void insert(char str[],int link[],int size,int first)
```

by

```
void insert(char str[],int link[],int& size,int& first)
```

to start of. Still might not work but atleast now the things you do actually do what you want them to do